# Bootstrap: wrapping text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following bootstrap code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
      <div style="width: 75px; background-color: #ccc">
        <img width="75" alt="picture" src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10" style="">
      Right content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On tablets and desktops, this code looks good. However, on smaller devices, `xs`, the right content flows into the image. I am trying to make the text just wrap on the right and not collide with the image.

I have a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2kb48p7e/1/) so you can see what I'm talking about. If you open the fiddle and resize the browser small enough, you'll see the right text overlap onto the image. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You have given col-xs-2 for the image holder.The width is so 25% or less.So on smaller screens Image will overflow the container

Comment: Personally I would just give the image container and the description container a class of `.col-xs-12` so that they both take up the whole row.

Comment: @Jhecht - Doing that would put the text under the image. What I want is the image to stay a constant 75 pixels, but the right content get smaller and wrap within its cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
      <div style="width: 75px; background-color: #ccc">
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="picture" src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-10 col-sm-10" style="">
      Right content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same Issue when I resize.

Comment: i recently found your changed qwestion. I will answer

Comment: why you fixed your width in child div of div.col-xs-2?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the width set.
Try this.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjou3khh/1/)**

HTML

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
          <div style="background-color: #ccc">
            <img class="test-image" alt="picture" src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10" style="">
          Right content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.test-image{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  min-width:25px;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the image gets smaller too as I resize the browser. I want to keep the image at a constant 75 pixels.

Comment: Try giving img-responsive class to the image.

Comment: Or with media query, set image width to 75px and display it as block element.

Answer (score 0):

It is becaue of the width of the col-xs-2.You can chage that.Or try an alternative solution like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div style="width: 75px; background-color: #ccc;display:table-cell;">
         <img width="75" alt="picture" src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" />
    </div>
     <div class=" " style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
        Right content
    </div>
</div></div></div>
```

Or with css flexboxes like

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12" style="display:flex">
    <div style="width: 75px; background-color: #ccc;flex:1;">
         <img width="75" alt="picture" src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" />
    </div>
     <div class=" " style="flex:1;vertical-align:middle;">
        Right content
     </div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: It wraps the text under the image. I'd prefer the text to stay put

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7dx9hbk0/3/ check this.Or you can use flex box to achieve that effect.http://jsfiddle.net/h9pzL33k/1/  Check this

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I know is to apply a direct width to element. You could theoretically alter the bootstrap 3 SCSS or LESS (whichever you use) and add in a special column class, but this is the most direct method.

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="width:75px" class="col-xs-2">
      <div style="width: 75px; background-color: #ccc">
        <img width="75" alt="picture" src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10" style="">
      Right content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```